# Custom slider AS3 sound seek

Tags: javascript, jquery, actionscript-3, flash

i made a custom slider and everything seems to be fine, but I am trying to create a seek function to make the slider move using `this.mySlider.sliderTrack.mouseX` position from `width:1000px`

I just need help figuring out how the math to make `mouseX` the new `channel.position`

`var newPercent = this.mySlider.sliderTrack.mouseX = playbackPercent;
snd.play(newPercent)`

```
var sliderKnob = this.mySlider.sliderKnob;
var sliderTrack = this.mySlider.sliderTrack;
var estimatedLength:int = Math.ceil(snd.length / (snd.bytesLoaded / snd.bytesTotal)); 
var playbackPercent:uint =  Math.round(100 * (channel.position / estimatedLength));
sliderKnob.x = playbackPercent;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can get the ratio between seeked position and total length**

```
var newPercent = this.mySlider.sliderTrack.mouseX  / 1000 /// 1000 px for your case
var totalDurationOfMedia = 3232 /// This comes from metadata, total length of the media
var whereToSeek = newPercent * totalDurationOfMedia
mediaPlayer.seek(whereToSeek);
```

Comment: action script 3 didn't have .seek but I made it work, thanks again!